# Why locate is faster than find?

Tags: find, locate

I was looking for a file in my source and tried both locate and find.
Surprisingly locate was searching in entire machine and was faster than find, which was searching only in current directory and sub directories.

Here are my shell commands for both:

```
find . -name vendorsetup.sh # takes 50 seconds to search all files in curren -sub directories.

locate vendorsetup.sh # takes 20 seconds to search file in whole machine.
```

Why this?

Comment: Mind you: try that with a file you just created and locate will NOT find it. find will find it ;) (locate is fast but less accurate than find).

Comment: 20 seconds for a 'locate' lookup sounds pretty slow. On my (rather slow) system it takes between 1-2 seconds to find anything:
`time locate nonexisting_file
locate nonexisting_file  1.46s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 1.483 total`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`locate` uses a database and periodically does an inventory of your file system. The database is optimized for searching. `find` needs to traverse the whole subdirectory, which is pretty fast, but not as fast as locate.

Comment: Also, thanks to the periodic inventory (`updatedb`), the results won't be quite as recent. This would succeed: `touch someuniquefilename; find / -name someuniquefilename`, but this would probably fail: `touch someuniquefilename; locate someuniquefilename`

Comment: however, you can run `sudo updatedb` and then `locate` will find new files

Answer (score 3):

About Locate :

> Locate uses an index that stores  in `/var/lib/slocate/`, that is
>   updated by a nightly Cron job. This nightly job typically runs at
>   about 1AM  or 2AM of local time, and completely scans your entire system
>   (including all connected drives). The resulting index is simply a list
>   of filenames.Search will be so fast because of already indexing done to every element in filesystem

But `find` is not like so,

everytime it will consider the search as fresh search and no storing of any cache of file location.

so it will take time to find.

hope that helps.

Comment: Hasn't `slocate` been replaced by `mlocate`? Also, AFAIK it does __not__ scan connected drives by default, in fact the standard `/etc/updatedb.conf` file specifically excludes paths like `/media` and remote filesystems such as NFS and SAMBA.

Comment: Also, I don't know about you, but my desktop is rarely online at 2am and yet locate still seems to be updated...

Comment: I believe the `locate` database is also updated on startup